# How to read a BufferedReader without clearing it

Tags: java, spring

I need to log the request's body before the Spring RestController is called.
To do this, I use an HandlerInterceptorAdapter and I do this :

```
if (request.getReader() != null) {
    String s;
    String body = "";
    while ((s = request.getReader().readLine()) != null) {
        body += s;
    }
    if (!StringUtil.isBlankOrNull(body)) {
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(body);
        return jsonBody.toString(2);
    }
}
```

My problem is that the reader is empty after this and it crash before calling the RestController.

What can I do to read the request's body without clearing the BufferedReader ?

Comment: You can only read the request once. You will have to wrap the request and reset it. Also Spring already has filters which do the logging I suggest you use those instead of rolling your own (or look at them for inspiration :) ).

Comment: @M.Deinum Completely incorrect. That's what `mark()` and `reset()` are for.

Comment: However `mark()` and `reset()` depend (usually) on the buffer size, which is not necessarily safe to trust.

Comment: Which don't work on the request based reader. Yu can only read the stream once after that it is parsed and you will get an exception. Reset/mark generally don't work with a `HttpServletRequest` is my experience.

Comment: I just tried to use mark() and reset() on the request.getReader() and, as @M.Deinum said, it doesn't work. I also tried to copy the Reader with apache IOUtils but this read the original Reader while creating the copy.

Comment: So you need to wrap the `Reader` in a `BufferedReader`, which does support `mark()/reset()`.